# Navigation li elements at the bottom using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to bootstrap and i am trying out the navigation at the bottom of the page with equal spaces between li elements but I couldn't accomplished. Would you please help me?

edit 1:When I use as follows, navigation li overlaps.

Here is the Html:

```
 <!-- Nav -->
        <nav>
            <ul class="navigation">
                <li class="link center bottom move"><a href="#about" title="About">About</a></li>
                <li class="link center bottom move"><a href="#contact" title="Contact"><span lang="tr">İLETİŞİM</span></a></li>
                <li class="link center bottom move"><a class="btn" href="#subscribe" title="Subscribe">Subscribe</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- End Nav -->
```

Here are the CSS:

```
body > header nav {
    height: 100%;
}
ul.navigation {
    font-family: "Raleway", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.navigation a {
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 0.25em 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}
.navigation a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-color: #FFF;
}
.navigation .link {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transform-origin: center;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center;
}
.navigation .link.side {
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 0
}
.navigation .link.bottom {
    bottom: 4em;
}
.navigation .link.middle {
    top: 49%;
}
.navigation .link.left {
    left: 4em;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.navigation .link.right {
    right: 4em;
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Here is the demo page:
[demo page](http://ioterm.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Adding style tag solved my issue.

```
<nav>
            <ul class="navigation">

            <li class="link bottom move" style="left:12em;"><a href="#contact" title="Contact"><span lang="tr">İLETİŞİM</span></a></li>
            <li class="link bottom move"><a href="#contact" title="Contact"><span lang="tr">İLETİŞİM</span></a></li>
            <li class="link bottom move" style="right:12em;"><a href="#contact" title="Contact"><span lang="tr">İLETİŞİM1</span></a></li>
            </ul>

        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using Bootstrap's [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) placed inside a sticy footer. This should keep the html elements in the right place depending on the screen width (also mobile screens). Adjust the `col-xs-*` to achieve the right amount of spacing.

```
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <a href="#about" title="About">About</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">  
      <a href="#contact" title="Contact"><span lang="tr">İLETİŞİM</span></a>         
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <a class="btn" href="#subscribe" title="Subscribe">Subscribe</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

The sticky `<footer>` can be found [here](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/) and the css [here](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/sticky-footer.css)

Comment: I do not want to use sticky footer. In my example, the li elements overlaps so I just need to set spacing between them.